# Make text in table cell to urls using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some tables and i am trying to make the contents in the table cell as urls if they start with http . The code i have tried is as follows. The issue is : it is becoming a hyperlink and not url.(for ex: if the table cell content is the text for https://www.google.com , the final link it is becoming is 
`"https://myapplicationlink/www.google.com"`.
I am not able to figure out why. Please help.

```
 var tables=document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
 for (x=0;x<tables.length;x++)
{
 var rows=tables[x].getElementsByTagName('TR');
 for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) 
  {
    var cells=rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (z=0;z<cells.length;z++)
    {


 //code for styling etc which i removed

 var hyp;var c;
      c=cells[z].innerHTML;
     if (c.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
         hyp="<a href=" + cells[z].innerHTML  +"</a>";
      c=hyp;
   cells[z].innerHTML = c;

}


 }


  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would get the bug you're describing, but you're not closing your href tag in your code...

```
hyp="<a href=" + cells[z].innerHTML  +"</a>";
```

should be

```
hyp="<a href=\"" + cells[z].innerHTML  +"\">some text here</a>";
```

Also, rather than drawing href into the cell you can convert the cell to be clickable like this

```
 var hyp;var c;
  c=cells[z].innerHTML;
 if (c.indexOf("http") >= 0)          
   cells[z].onclick = (function(url){self.location.href = url})(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're inserting invalid HTML for one. This line:

```
hyp="<a href=" + cells[z].innerHTML  +"</a>";
```

Should actually be:

```
hyp='<a href="' + cells[z].innerHTML  + '">' + cells[z].innerHTML + '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i did try this initially , but removed ">" as it was appending ">" to the text for ex: www.google.com"> and finally the link location  becomes myapplication link\www.google.com">

Comment: Make sure you've got quotes in all the right places. That was your main problem.